# Access, detect last name if the first letter is not capital letter

Tags: ms-access, namespaces, detect, capitalization

If I import new set of data of last and first name, how can I detect last name which the first letter is not capital letter or space before name??? and after detect it, how can I see the list of result?

such as

Name :

Lee  Arvin

kwon Tony

kwon, Tony

Detect :

kwon Tony

kwon, Tony

Answer (score 0):

Look for the first `LEFT` character then check if the ASCii code is within 65 to 90 range